# Laravel. Как передать значение из PIVOT в следующий запрос

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Есть таблицы `geographic_code`, `zone_map`, `tariff_zone`, связующая таблица `phone_zone_map_item`.

Столбцы:

`geographic_code` : code

`zone_map`: id, title

`tariff_zone`: id, title

`phone_zone_map_item`: map_id(zone_map:id), code(geographic_code:code), zone_id(tariff_zone:id)

Получаю зону с географическими кодами, с помощью связующей таблицы:

```
ZoneMap::query()->with(["codes"])->whereId(12)->first()
-----------------------
public function codes(){
    return $this->belongsToMany(
        GeographicCode::class,
        "phone_zone_map_item_" . $this->config["id"],
        "map_id", "code", null, "code"
    )->withPivot("zone_id");
}
```

Дальше мне нужно для каждого географического кода получить его тарифную зону, ID тарифной зоны это `zone_id` в связующей таблице. Думал что сработает вот так:

```
public function codes(){
        return $this->belongsToMany(
            GeographicCode::class,
            "phone_zone_map_item_" . $this->config["id"],
            "map_id", "code", null, "code"
        )->withPivot("zone_id")->with("zone");
}
```

в моделе GeographicCode

```
public function zone(){
    return $this->belongsTo(TariffZone::class, "id", "zone_id"); 
}
```

Но значение PIVOT не передается. Каким образом можно передать zone_id из pivot в следующий запрос? На выходе я хочу получить следующий массив:

```
[
  "id" => 12,
  "title" => Карта зон,
  "codes" => [
     0 => [
        "code" => 79542,
        "zone" => [
           "id" => 13,
           "title" => "Внутризоновая связь" 
        ]
     ] 
  ]
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Прошу прошения. Было несколько ошибок:

1. в таблице `geographic_code` не было primary ключа.
2. не правильно был составлена связь `"к одному через"(hasOneThrough)`

Вот так выглядит код:

```
ZoneMap::with("codes.zone")->whereId(12)->first()


class ZoneMap extends Model {

    public function codes(){
        return $this->hasManyThrough(
            GeographicCode::class,
            TariffZoneByGeographicCode::class,
            "map_id", "code", null, "code"
        );
    }

}

class GeographicCode extends Model {

    public function direction(){
        return $this->hasOne(Direction::class, "id", "dest_id");
    }

    public function zone(){
        return $this->hasOneThrough(
            TariffZone::class,
            TariffZoneByGeographicCode::class,
            "code", "id", null,"zone_id"
        );
    }
}
```